# I am getting this error in my react app with 'Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute'

Tags: reactjs, oauth, react-google-login

I'm making a react app with Google Authentication and I get this error: 'Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute'

my code:

```
<GoogleLogin
  clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
  render={renderProps => (
    <Button variant='contained' color='primary' onClick={renderProps.onClick} disabled={renderProps.disabled}>
      Login with Google
    </Button>
  )}
  onSuccess={onGoogleSuccess}
  onFailure={onGoogleFail}
  cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
/>
```

Comment: jus wondering did you resolve this error and how did you do it?